# Type 'Observable<string | null>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have code:

```
id$!: Observable<string | null>;
 characterDetail$!: Observable<CharacterData | undefined>;   //??????

 constructor(
   private router: ActivatedRoute,
   private store$: Store
 ) {} 

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.id$ = of(this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
   this.getCharacterDetail();
   this.characterDetail$ = this.store$.select(charDetailsSelector);
 }

 getCharacterDetail() { 
   if (!this.id$) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: this.id$ }));

 }
```

and error in this part:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The function, which we cannot see, `getCharDetailsData` expects an string input for id. But `this.id$` is an Observable. It seems like you would want a `BehaviorSubject` instead and use:

```
getCharacterDetail() { 
   if (!this.id$.value) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: this.id$.value }));

 }
```

Comment: How to implement BehaviorSubject instead of Observable?

Comment: Instead of Observable you use `BehaviorSubject` as type. You initialize it with `new BehaviorSubject(undefined)` (though I would suggest using null instead of undefined) and then insert new vaule using `next`. The `BehaviorSuject` basically saves the last value and does not lose it right away.

Answer (score 0):

**First Problem:**

In onInit you converted id from router snapshot to observable using the 'of' operator which would emit only one value because the source is a single from the snapshot and would not be reactive to value change in actual route

**Secondly:**

Rather than creating an observable you can remove it from onInit and do something like this in the `getCharacterDetail`

```
getCharacterDetail() { 
   const id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   if (!id) {
     return;
   }
   this.store$.dispatch(getCharDetailsData({id: id}));

}
```